# developing code in multiple locations

Tags: windows, mac, versioning

I have two machines (one is a mac one is a pc), and I develop on both machines but only run "production" on the pc.

Now, I sometimes face an issue where both machine PC and machine MAC have different versions of the same code, and I would like them to share a common source.

I know this solution must exist but I have no ideat what it is called/how to start.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest (works for me) to get a git server (say either git or private git) and synchronize repositories with server.

Not only you get extra security, so your files are stored in 3 places, also you have a nice version management system at hand.

Comment: +1. git or some similar sort of source control is the solution here. Don't do file sharing. Use source control, whether it's git or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share out the code location (standard windows file share) and access that from your Mac? If you can, that would be the simplest solution, since you can edit/compile/test your code on the Mac and then do your final builds on the PC.

If you're curious about ensuring version control and checking old code, do some googling on 'source control' and SVN/Git/CVS.

Hope that points you in the right direction